# How to pass data between UITableVIews using UUID in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

I have two `UITableViewController`s. I am using Core Data and save text with `uuid`. My `firstTableViewController` contains some cells and when you click one of them, it is segued to `secondTableViewController` where you can create cells by `UIActionController` like below.

In my firstTableViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "note"){

        let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
        //Core Data
        let item: Folder
        item = self.folders[indexPath!.row]

        let dvc = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
        dvc.topTItle = item.name!
    }
}
```

In my secondViewController:

```
var notes = [Note]()
var topTItle = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = topTItle

    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(NoteTableViewController.setFolder))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    getData()
}

let save = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: {
    (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    let textInput = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    //toptitle is basically the title of the navigation

    self.singelton.addNote(name: textInput.text!, uuid: self.topTItle + uuid)


    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.getData()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})


func getData(){
    notes = singelton.getFolderData()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, the newly created cell does not only belong to the cell from the `firsttableViewController`, but also all cells from `firstTableViewController` have the same data when you go to the `secondTableViewController`.

So as you can see in the code above, I used `toptitle` and `uuid` but it is not working.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you problem is. Please add more details about what you are trying to achieve and what does not work. May be attach some screenshots if necessary.

Comment: you want to show data in firsttableViewController after saving the data from secondTableViewController ..?